# How to add day and month to a missing date?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an input Excel file where I have a column where I have some dates.
The problem arises when there is some inconsistency because not all of them respect the following dd.mm.yyyy.

As such some lack the dd. having the mm.yyyy and some lack dd.mm. thus having just the yyyy

I am looking for a way to add 01 as dd in the cells where there is just mm.yyyy and 01.01 in the cells where there is just yyyy.

I am trying to run a VBA in another Excel that would target the Input Excel based on a selection

```
Sub addddmm()
Dim columnValues  As Range, i As Long

Set columnValues = Selection


For i = 1 To columnValues.Rows.Count
    If columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = "in the format of mm.yyyy" Then add 01.mm.yyyy

    End If
    If columnValues.Cells(i, 1).Value = "in the format of yyyy" Then add 01.01.yyyy

    End If
Next
```

End Sub

Many thanks!

Comment: `Like` might be useful. Does depend if you're dealing with dates or "text-that-looks-like-dates."

Comment: Hi and thanks for the comment, at the moment the column where the dates are stored displays "number stored as text". I have 60% of the dates as dd.mm.yyyy whilst the other 40% are either mm.yyyy or yyyy. So I have to target the mm.yyyy and yyyy cells and add 01. in front of mm.yyyy and 01.01. in front of yyyy

Comment: Try `Like "##.####"` and `Like "####"` for your two conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, perhaps use `Like`:

```vb
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In columnValues
    If cell.Value Like "##.####" Then
        cell.Value = "01." & cell.Value
    ElseIf cell.Value Like "####" Then
        cell.Value = "01.01." & cell.Value
    End If
Next
```